# encontrar intersecções em dois graficos em python

Tags: python, funções, matemática, gráfico

Eu tenho um código bem simples mas funcional. Ele obedece a duas funções matemáticas, testando diferentes valores de x e retornando as coordenadas do ponto caso o resultado das duas funções sejam o mesmo (y):

```
def funcs():
    for x in range(-100, 100):
        funcA = (x**2) + x - 2 
        funcB = 6 - x
        if funcA == funcB:
            print("###intersecção enctontrada###") 
            print(f'({x},{funcA})')
        else: 
            pass


funcs()
```

output:

```
###intersecção enctontrada###
(-4,10)
###intersecção enctontrada###
(2,4)
```

Mas eu tenho um grande problema, isso só funciona quando a intersecção se encontra quando o valor de x é um número **inteiro**, quando a intersecção ocorre quando o valor é quebrado, ele não mostra nada.

O Python suporta até **16 casas decimais**, e fazer um range de todas as casas decimais é completamente inviável. Então eu pensei que talvez seria possível fazer o Python parar de calcular as casas decimais depois de um certo número de casas decimais, pois eu acredito que se eu apenas arredondar o valor não impedirá o Python de contar as outras casas.

E eu preciso de uma solução prática de resolver esse problema e retornar todas as intersecções independente se são inteiros ou não.

**alguém me ajuda, por favor, obrigado.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da matemática, sabemos que as interseções de duas curvas podem ser definidas igualando as funções geradoras. Isto é, se você possui duas funções, A(x) e B(x), então a interseção ocorrerá nos valores de x tal que A(x) = B(x). Para encontrar os valores de x, basta resolver a equação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Igualando as duas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resolvendo essa equação de segundo grau, você obterá:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, encontrará os valores de x=2 e x=-4 que resolvem a equação.

De forma dinâmica, você pode utilizar a biblioteca [`sympy`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html) para isso.

```py
import sympy

x = sympy.symbols('x')

A = x**2 + x - 2
B = 6 - x

equation = sympy.Eq(A, B)

print( sympy.solveset(equation) )
# FiniteSet(-4, 2)
```

Veja que o Python resolveu a equação para você e retornou um conjunto finito de soluções contendo o -4 e 2. Caso queira o par `(x, f(x))` como saída, basta fazer:

```py
solutions = sympy.solveset(equation)

for s in solutions:
  print(s, A.subs(x, s))

# -4 10
# 2 4
```

Comment: Cara, você é incrível, salvou meu dia

Answer (score -1):

No Python, usar o `for i in range` te retorna apenas valores inteiros.

Para você obter valores do tipo .float, uma possível solução seria:

```
import numpy as np
def funcs():
    for x in np.arange(-100.0, 100.0, 0.1, dtype = float):
```

Porém como o Woss respondeu acima, acho que sua equações retornam apenas esses valores, precisaríamos testar outra equação (com os pontos de intersecção conhecidos) para testarmos a hipótese de retornar os valores float.

Muito legal sua pergunta!

links uteis:

[Python - Float Range](https://www.techbeamers.com/python-float-range/#:%7E:text=NumPy%20linspace%20function%20to%20generate%20float%20range,-NumPy%20has%20another&text=the%20specified%20no.-,of%20float%20numbers.,%3D%3E%20Default%20value%20is%20True.)

[How to print float number using foor loop](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_print_float_number_in_python_using_for_loop)

Comment: Nesse caso nem o range de floats resolverá, pois mesmo definindo um passo de 0.1, ainda não será todos os valores possíveis. Sem contar que limitar o range de -100 até 100 também reduz muito o conjunto de possíveis soluções. A solução pode estar fora desse intervalo. Ao usar a sympy não temos nenhuma dessas limitações.

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO, VOCÊ AJUDOU MUITO!!